# Integer multiplication using strings as input C++

Tags: c++, string

Whenever I feed single digit input to the following code, the answer comes out to be in 4 digits.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

int makeEqual(string &s1, string &s2)
{
    int len1 = s1.length();
    int len2 = s2.length();

    //cout<<"Lenght 1 :: "<<len1<<endl;
    //cout<<"Lenght 2 :: "<<len2<<endl;

    if(len1>len2)
    {
        for(int i=0; i<(len1-len2); i++)
            s2='0'+s2;  
        //cout<<"Return value is :: "<<len1<<endl;
        return len1;
    }
    else if(len2>len1)
    {
        for(int i=0; i<len2-len1; i++)
            s1='0'+s1;
        //cout<<"Return value is :: "<<len2<<endl;
        return len2;
    }
    else
        return len1;
}
int singleMultiply(string s1, string s2)
{
    return (s1[0]-'0')*(s2[0]-'0');
}
long int multiply(string a, string b)
{
    int n=makeEqual(a,b);
    if(n==0) return 0;
    if(n==1) return (singleMultiply(a,b));
    return 0;
}
int main()
{
    cout<<singleMultiply("9","9");
    return 0;
}
```

The output is 0020 instead of 20. 
Can anyone please explain the logic behind this?

EDIT: I included all the code I wrote. Actually am new to programming, and am trying to work out code for Karatsuba Algorithm on base 10.

Comment: http://www.compileonline.com/compile_cpp_online.php  here it outputs "20"

Comment: It outputs "20" to me too (g++ (Debian 4.4.5-8) 4.4.5)... BTW, your code won't work for integers greater than 10.

Comment: Can't reproduce. Prints `20`. I predict your actual code is different, and the problem is in the part of it you haven't shown.

Comment: Don't see any problem, I get `20`.

Comment: In my gcc, it shows 0020.

@GrijeshChauhan : I actually wanted to understand the logic and not a way to correct it.

Comment: @LarryPel : Yeah its just a part of the main project I am working in.

Comment: @psyc0der Write a *small* program that reproduces it and post it here *in its entirety*. (Or don't bother with it, since you will probably figure out what the problem is when making such a small program).

Comment: You can try adding the "dec" keyword when printing: cout << dec << singleMultiply("5","4");

Comment: psyc0der read @IgorTandetnik comment, post complete code.

Comment: @LarryPel : Adding dec doesnt help. Same strange output

Comment: I see that `main` calls `singleMultiply`, which should multiply 9*9 and return 81. ***The End***.  Why do you expect output `20`?  What is all the rest of the apparently unused code for?

Comment: @abelenky : I used '20' as example. This one gives `0081` as output. And the other code is posted as I was asked to post it.

Comment: How do you compile and execute this?

Comment: The standard g++ procedure.

Comment: What is "the standard g++ procedure"? There are roughly 10,000,000 permutations of `g++` invocations. What is preventing you from telling us which you are using, precisely? Are you trolling?

Comment: Oops. Didnt know that. Sorry. 

g++ prog.cpp -o prog.out
./prog.out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect your `cout` has a  `setw(4) << setfill('0')` somewhere that we cannot see.

That would produce `0020` as you describe.

I recommend trying:

```
cout << setw(0) << setfill(' ') << singleMultiply("9","9");
```

---

Begin looking for problems this way:

```
int singleMultiply(string s1, string s2)
{
    cout << "Input 1 is " << s1[0] << endl;
    cout << "Input 2 is " << s2[0] << endl;

    cout << "Oper 1 is " << s1[0]-'0' << endl;
    cout << "Oper 2 is " << s2[0]-'0' << endl;

    cout << "Answer is " << (s1[0]-'0')*(s2[0]-'0') << endl;
    printf("Answer (via printf) is %d\n", (s1[0]-'0')*(s2[0]-'0'));

    return (s1[0]-'0')*(s2[0]-'0');
}
```

Comment: I did copy my entire code. So you can rule that possibility out I guess

Answer (score 0):

Your function implementation is limited to single digits, but you are taking in strings (which could be multiple digits.

If you just want to multiply single digits, change your signature to

```
int singleMultiply(char s1, char s2)
{
  return (s1-'0')*(s2-'0');
}

int main()
{
    cout << singleMultiply('5','4');
    return 0;
}
```

If you want to be more generic:

```
int singleMultiply(string s1, string s2)
{
    // deprecated method, but still the easiest to understand
    //return atoi(s1.c_str()) * atoi(s2.c_str());
    // updated method
    long l1 = strtol(s1.c_str(), NULL, 10);
    long l2 = strtol(s2.c_str(), NULL, 10);
    return l1 * l2;
}

int main()
{
    cout << singleMultiply("50", "40");
    return 0;
}
```

EDIT:  After your edit, it is apparent you are doing FAR more work than you need to.  `atoi`/`strtol` will do the integer conversion for you (and do it better than what you are trying to do).

I had some time to kill, so I think this is what you are trying to do (though, I don't know why you would want to):

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>

std::string karatsuba(std::string lhs, std::string rhs)
{
    if (lhs.length() != rhs.length())
    {
        if (lhs.length() < rhs.length())
        {
            int diff = rhs.length() - lhs.length();
            lhs.insert(0, diff, '0');
        }
        else
        {
            int diff = lhs.length() - rhs.length();
            rhs.insert(0, diff, '0');
        }
    }

    if (lhs.length() == 1 && rhs.length() == 1)
    {
        long l = std::strtol(lhs.c_str(), NULL, 10);
        long r = std::strtol(rhs.c_str(), NULL, 10);
        long ret = l * r;
        std::stringstream ss;
        ss << ret;
        return ss.str();
    }

    int m = lhs.length();
    int midpoint = m / 2;
    std::string lowlhs(lhs.begin() + midpoint, lhs.end());
    std::string lowrhs(rhs.begin() + midpoint, rhs.end());
    std::string highlhs(lhs.begin(), lhs.begin()  + midpoint);
    std::string highrhs(rhs.begin(), rhs.begin()  + midpoint);

    long addLhs = std::strtol(lowlhs.c_str(), NULL, 10) + std::strtol(highlhs.c_str(), NULL, 10);
    long addRhs = std::strtol(lowrhs.c_str(), NULL, 10) + std::strtol(highrhs.c_str(), NULL, 10);
    std::stringstream ssL;
    std::stringstream ssR;
    ssL << addLhs;
    ssR << addRhs;

    std::string sZ0 = karatsuba(lowlhs, lowrhs);
    std::string sZ1 = karatsuba(ssL.str(), ssR.str());
    std::string sZ2 = karatsuba(highlhs, highrhs);

    long z0 = std::strtol(sZ0.c_str(), NULL, 10);
    long z1 = std::strtol(sZ1.c_str(), NULL, 10);
    long z2 = std::strtol(sZ2.c_str(), NULL, 10);
    long highOrder = static_cast<long>(std::pow(10.0, static_cast<double>(m)));
    long lowOrder = static_cast<long>(std::pow(10.0, static_cast<double>(m / 2)));
    long result = (z2 * highOrder) + ((z1 - z2 - z0) * lowOrder) + z0;
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << result;
    return ss.str();
}

int main()
{
    std::string lhs = "20";
    std::string rhs = "45";
    std::string result = karatsuba(lhs, rhs);

    std::cout << "Multiplied:  " << lhs << " x " << rhs << " = " << result << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I dont understand. Even if input is of multiple digits, I am accessing only the digit at index 0. Logically, that shouldn't be a problem I guess

Comment: I had no clue about atoi. Thanks for that! :)

Comment: It is a problem in that it will give you incorrect results.  If you call the function with "50" and "40", for example, you will get the result of `20` instead of your expected result of `2000`.  In either case, `atoi` is the better choice, but if you only limit it to 1 character input, you can do the subtraction from '0' and still get correct results.

Comment: No actually this function is meant to mutiply single digits only.
And how to I limit the input to 1 character using atoi?

Comment: You do that by limiting your input to single characters (the first solution I posted).

Comment: Actually, the program intends to accept multiple digit strings as input, and break them down into half and then calculate the product recursively. (Karatsuba Algorithm)
So putting in string as parameter was the obvious thing, as the program splits the main string recursively. I haven't written the splitting part yet though.

Comment: `atoi` has been deprecated in POSIX for many, many years. Why are you recommending the use of this outdated function? Prefer `strtol`

Comment: @Lightness:  Ah, forgot about that (it is still part of the C Standard Library).  Will fix the example.

Comment: @psyc0der:  So you are trying to implement a very inefficient multiplication method?